# Differential Equations Including Combinaton of Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I am involved with a kind of differential equation but I don't know how to approach it or classify it.

$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = f(y(x),x(s),s)$

Where $x=x(s)$

Assume that I have 2 of those equations and my aim is to solve y(x). However x also depends on a parameter s and I want to find a y(x) such that above equation is satisfied for $a<s<b$.

So, it includes combination or some kind of nested function structure. While I was searching something about such equations, I have ended up with differential equations including functionals, integral equations and some parametric ODE's but I haven't exactly figured it out.

What can be done is, assuming that $s=s_0$ or taking the s as a parameter and varying it, get different solutions for $y(x)$ but still as you may understand I am kind of lost. As an example;

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y*(x+s)$

And since we have two unknowns let be a 2nd equation;

$\frac{dx}{ds}y=\frac{dy}{dx}*cos(x+s)$

(Of course these are nonlinear ones and probably have no easy solution or one can use seperable equations approach etc. but I just want to learn how to classify and learn something about such equations)

(y and (x+s) are in multiplication y is y(x) here and x=x(s) so as s changes also x get affected and y )

Can you suggest differential equations topics related to such equations to learn about or am I missing some very easy part in there?

Comment: If we think of $x, y$ as the generalized coordinates of a (Lagrangian) mechanical system, and of $s$, as time, then your ODE relate the generalized coordinates to the generalized moments $x' = dx/ds, \; y' = dy/ds$.  In the special case you've presented, the moment $dx/ds$ is absent from the equation, so the system is independent of it.

Formally, you can try expressing $dy/dx = y'/x'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanations are quite unstructured and unclear, but let me try to speculate. 
You have something like 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= f\big(y(x), x(s), s\big)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= g\big(y(x), x(s), s\big)
\end{align}
Is this what you have? Then simply $x=x(s)$ and then $y = y(x) = y(x(s)) = y(s)$, i.e. treat $y$ as a function of $s$. Then $\frac{dy}{ds} = \frac{dy}{dx} \, \frac{dx}{ds}$ and so 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{ds} &= f\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)\, \frac{dx}{ds}\\
&= f\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)\, g\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= g\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)
\end{align}
which is the ODE system 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{ds} 
&= f\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)\, g\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= g\big(y(s), x(s), s\big)
\end{align} or in shorter notation
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{ds} 
&= f\big(y, x, s\big)\, g\big(y, x, s\big)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} &= g\big(y, x, s\big)
\end{align}